# CSS:nth-of-type in for loop doesent extract text

Tags: css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to extract the strings `text_i_wantA`, `text_i_wantB`, `text_i_wantC` from each of the **3** children of **each** of the 10 `div class = col-12`. For readability i only included two of the otherwise same structured divs. For now i am fine if it doesent return the actual `.content[0]` as i can also parse that later.

Here is the full code:

```
title,date,name,number = [],[],[],[]
while True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    for div in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'title':'ad i'}):
        titl = div.get_text(strip=True)
        title.append(titl)
    else:
        break
    for col in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'col-12'})[1::2]:
        row = []
        for entry in col.select('div.row div'):
            target = entry.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
            row.append(target[0].strip())
        name.append(row[0])
        date.append(row[1])
        number.append(row[2])  

    next_btn = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".page-next button")
    if next_btn:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(next_btn[0]).click().perform()
        time.sleep(4)
    else:
        break
driver.close()
```

Expected output:

```
title = ["text_i_already_have1", "text_i_already_have2", ...]

date = ["text_i_wantA", "text_i_wantAA", ...]

name = ["text_i_wantB", "text_i_wantBB", ...]

number = ["text_i_wantC", "text_i_wantCC", ...]
```

**Problem:** Actual output **with slice** `[1::2]`

```
title = ["text_i_already_have1", "text_i_already_have2", ...]
date = ['text_i_wantA', 'text_i_wantAA', ...],
name = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
number = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Is it a problem with my css or the loop itself?

The first line works fine:
`print(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'col-12'}))` **without slice** gives me the list of the divs i want to extract the `text_i_want` from:

```
[<div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/url" target="_blank" title="ad i">
                                text_i_already_have1
                            </a>
                        </div>, 
                  <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    date: text_i_wantA
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        source: text_i_wantB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    number: text_i_wantC
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="url" title="text_i_dont_want">
                                            text_i_dont_want
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>,
                 <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/url" target="_blank" title="ad i">
                                text_i_already_have2
                            </a>
                        </div>, 
                 <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    date: text_i_wantAA
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        source: text_i_wantBB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    number: text_i_wantCC
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="/url" title="text_i_dont_want">
                                            text_i_dont_want
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>,
                  <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/url" target="_blank" title="ad i">
                                text_i_already_have
                            </a>
                        </div>, 
                  <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    date: text_i_wantAAA
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        source: text_i_wantBBB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    number: text_i_wantCCC
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="/url" title="text_i_dont_want">
                                            text_i_dont_want
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>, 
                 <div class="col-12">
                            .  
                            . 
                            . 
                            . 
                        </div>]
```

The `text_i_dont_want` is always inside the `<span class="processlink">` element, which itself is the last child of one of the 3 `<div class="row">` elements which are inside each of the 10_per_page `<div class="col-12">` elements.

Comment: Your question is unclear; given the sample html in the question, what **exactly** is your expected output?

Comment: That's better, but you should, first, edit your question and add the desired output there, not in a comment, and second (and more importantly) add to your sample html another element with text that you **don't** want.

Comment: Just to confirm: the text you **don't** want is always inside a `<span class="processlink">` element, which itself is a (the last?) child of one of the 3 (or more?) `<div class="row">` elements which are inside each of the multiple `<div class="col-12">` elements?

Comment: Yes, precicely. The `text_i_dont_want` is always inside the `<span class="processlink">` element, which itself is the last child of one of the 3 `<div class="row">` elements which are inside each of the multiple `<div class="col-12">` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly now, this should get you there (or at least close enough):

```
date,name,number = [],[],[]
for col in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'col-12'}):
    row = []
    for entry in col.select('div.row div'):
        target = entry.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
        row.append(target[0].strip())
    date.append(row[0])
    name.append(row[1])
    number.append(row[2])
```

The output of, for example, `print(date)`, should be:

```
['text_i_wantA', 'text_i_wantAA']
```

Comment: Thank you, `name` has the right values. Unfortunately `date = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']` and `number = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']` only contain empty strings.. I see you approach though

Comment: @id345678 It works fine with the sample html in the question. But, of course, the sample is not always representative of the actual html. Nonetheless, the approach should work with the actual html once the appropriate tweaks are made to the code. As to the tweaks, you'll have to try different things and see what works.

Comment: Sounds good and it works for `name`. But i dont get why it doesent for the other as the structure is clear. I added the whole `outerHTML` to the question above. It doesent work for `date` and `number` but i dont get any error either

Comment: @id345678 Don't know what the problem is. Using your updated html as the source for `soup`, I get 3 lists with 10 items each. The `name` list seems to refer to `source` instead, but otherwise everything works fine.

Comment: When i remove the slice `[1::2]`, it thows `IndexError: list index out of range` at `date.append(row[0])`. I updated the html to make clear why i needed to slice.